# reshape repeated measurements long to wide in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape

here is some example data

```
>mydat <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,6),rep(2,4)),treat=c("a","a","a","b","b","c","a","b","d","f"))
>mydat
id treat
1   1     a
2   1     a
3   1     a
4   1     b
5   1     b
6   1     c
7   2     a
8   2     b
9   2     d
10  2     f
```

how can I count the treatments for each id and put them in a separate column?

It should look like this:

```
>result <- data.frame(id=c(1,2),a=c(3,1),b=c(2,1),c=c(1,0),d=c(0,1),f=c(0,1))
>result
    id a b c d f
  1  1 3 2 1 0 0
  2  2 1 1 0 1 1
```

thanks

Comment: a simple `table(mydat)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydat, id~treat, value.var='treat', length)
```

Or

```
 table(mydat)
```

Or

```
 xtabs(rep(1, nrow(mydat))~id+treat, mydat)
```

Comment: wow that was fast, perfect, thanks!

Comment: I think a reshaping faq is in order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydat %>% count(id, treat) %>% spread(treat, n, fill = 0)
```